# Possible to set selected value for f.select whilst using string of options + html_safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I currently have 3 HTML selects for: currency, timezone, and country. The currency one looks like this:

```
<%= f.select(:currency_code, '
  <option selected>Select Currency</option>
  <option value="AUD">(AUD) Australian Dollar</option>
  <option value="BRL">(BRL) Brazilian Real</option>
  <option value="CAD">(CAD) Canadian Dollar</option>
  <option value="CZK">(CZK) Czech Koruna</option>
  <option value="DKK">(DKK) Danish Krone</option>
  <option value="EUR">(EUR) Euro</option>
  <option value="HKD">(HKD) Hong Kong Dollar</option>
  <option value="HUF">(HUF) Hungarian Forint</option>
  <option value="ILS">(ILS) Israeli New Sheqel</option>
  <option value="JPY">(JPY) Japanese Yen</option>
  <option value="MYR">(MYR) Malaysian Ringgit</option>
  <option value="MXN">(MXN) Mexican Peso</option>
  <option value="NOK">(NOK) Norwegian Krone</option>
  <option value="NZD">(NZD) New Zealand Dollar</option>
  <option value="PHP">(PHP) Philippine Peso</option>
  <option value="PLN">(PLN) Polish Zloty</option>
  <option value="GBP">(GBP) Pound Sterling</option>
  <option value="SGD">(SGD) Singapore Dollar</option>
  <option value="SEK">(SEK) Swedish Krona</option>
  <option value="CHF">(CHF) Swiss Franc</option>
  <option value="TWD">(TWD) Taiwan New Dollar</option>
  <option value="THB">(THB) Thai Baht</option>
  <option value="TRY">(TRY) Turkish Lira</option>
  <option value="USD">(USD) U.S. Dollar</option>'.html_safe, {}, { class: "form-control" }) %>
```

I realize that I can use `options_for_select` etc so that I can use `selected:`. However, is there a way to set the selected value using a string of options + `html_safe` as above?

Right now, if a user selects `BRL` as their currency when the form rerenders that option will not be selected.

edit: 
Not sure why I'm being downvoted when I am not aware of this being answered on SO elsewhere. There's at least 100 of these types of questions, but none of them address what I'm referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that passing a list of options as a plain string to `select` helper is using Rails features in a very limited way. Don't fight the framework, let it do all the heavy lifting for you. It's much easier to work with arrays of options than with a string.

Answering your question:

> However, is there a way to set the selected value using a string of options + html_safe as above? Right now, if a user selects `BRL` as their currency when the form rerenders that option will not be selected.

Yup, it's possible:

```
currency = 'BRL'
options = '
  <option selected>Select Currency</option>
  <option value="AUD">(AUD) Australian Dollar</option>
  <option value="BRL">(BRL) Brazilian Real</option>
  <option value="CAD">(CAD) Canadian Dollar</option>
  <option value="CZK">(CZK) Czech Koruna</option>
  <option value="DKK">(DKK) Danish Krone</option>
  <option value="EUR">(EUR) Euro</option>
  <option value="HKD">(HKD) Hong Kong Dollar</option>
  <option value="HUF">(HUF) Hungarian Forint</option>
  <option value="ILS">(ILS) Israeli New Sheqel</option>
  <option value="JPY">(JPY) Japanese Yen</option>
  <option value="MYR">(MYR) Malaysian Ringgit</option>
  <option value="MXN">(MXN) Mexican Peso</option>
  <option value="NOK">(NOK) Norwegian Krone</option>
  <option value="NZD">(NZD) New Zealand Dollar</option>
  <option value="PHP">(PHP) Philippine Peso</option>
  <option value="PLN">(PLN) Polish Zloty</option>
  <option value="GBP">(GBP) Pound Sterling</option>
  <option value="SGD">(SGD) Singapore Dollar</option>
  <option value="SEK">(SEK) Swedish Krona</option>
  <option value="CHF">(CHF) Swiss Franc</option>
  <option value="TWD">(TWD) Taiwan New Dollar</option>
  <option value="THB">(THB) Thai Baht</option>
  <option value="TRY">(TRY) Turkish Lira</option>
  <option value="USD">(USD) U.S. Dollar</option>'

options.sub(' selected', '').sub(%r{("#{currency}")}, '\1 selected').html_safe
```

However, see my note at the top of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're making this more complicated than it really needs to be. You don't even need to explicitly call options_for_select or use `.html_safe`.

To create a select from an arbitrary list you can just pass an array:

```
<%= f.select(:currency_code, ["AUD", "BRL"]) %>
```

If you want different values and labels then pass an array of pairs:

```
<%= f.select(:currency_code, [["(AUD) Australian Dollar", "AUD"], ["(BRL) Brazilian Real", "BRL"]]) %>
```

If you have the currencies declared as a hash you can convert it to a set of pairs with:

```
hash = { "AUD" => "(AUD) Australian Dollar", "BRL" => "(BRL) Brazilian Real" }
hash.map { |value, label| [label, value] }
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I did try (poorly) to convey that I understood these methods existed, I just didn't want to write out all three selects by hand that way, or persist them in the database (yet). Thats at least an hours work on something I'd rather not do upfront for a side project and I assumed there _must_ be a way to use html and still have it select the users option. I'm a rails noob and contrary to your opening comment I was actually trying to make it less complicated/time consuming.